# Temporary id for database insertion

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Says I'm building a blog system. So for a blog post, the user will be able to write text and upload media file. Here's the flow behind :

1. an insert query is created when user click new post.
2. with that id it can save the blog content, both text and uploaded media.

the problem with this approach is many empty table record have to be deleted to optimize my db. I need to use this approach as I'm using nosql db (mongodb), so the media files' name have to have blog post id as references.

Answer (score 0):

Most database drivers for MongoDB allow you to generate ObjectIDs on the client-side. If you set the `_id` field of a document to such a generated ObjectID, MongoDB will use it instead of one generated on the database. This allows you to create a group of referencing documents on the application-side and then insert them all at once.

However, it *might* be more appropriate in your use-case to embed all the sub-documents in the blog-post-document and store it all in the database as one document.

Comment: drivers for mongodb to generate ID on client side?Got such thing?

Comment: @Jennifer Every API for MongoDB I have ever seen offers that. But you aren't saying what technology you are using for developing your application, so I can't point you to the documentation.